# (de)serialize an object(Hashmap) from an XML of this form with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

XML:

JAVA Hashmap:
map = {key1=text1,key2=text2}

this doesn't work. why?

```
String xml = "<nodes><node id=\"key1\"><![CDATA[text1]]></node><node id="\key2\"><![CDATA[text2]]></node></nodes>";

XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("nodes", Map.class);
xs.alias("node", String.class);
xs.useAttributeFor("id",String.class);
Map<String,String> map= (Map<String,String>) xs.fromXML(xml);
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can define your XML structure you should check the [Map Converter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converters.html) and adjust your XML.

If not, you should write your own [custom converter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html). You can see [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/unmarshalling-HashMap-td22595071.html) to check an implementation similar to your needs.